# Hurst Exponent calculator

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, signal-processing

I am aiming to compute the Hurst Exponent of a 1-D signal time series in Python.  For now, I have one existing function `hurst(sig)` which returns the Hurst exponent of `sig` as a float.  Unfortunately, the code runs *very slowly* even for signals with only ~7500 data points.  My main concerns are:

1. Calculate the computational complexity of my algorithm given the size of `sig`.
2. Reduce computational complexity of the algorithm.
3. Reduce run-time (~1s).
4. Improve readability and address style convention as applies.

My code, awaiting your feedback:

```
import numpy as np

def hurst(sig: np.ndarray) -> float:
    """Compute the Hurst exponent of sig.


    arguments
        sig -- 1D signal
    returns
        hurst_exponent -- float
    """

    n = sig.size # num timesteps
    t = np.arange(1, n + 1)
    y = sig.cumsum() # marginally more efficient than: np.cumsum(sig)
    mean_t = y / t # running mean

    s_t = np.zeros(n)
    r_t = np.zeros(n)

    for i in range(n):
        s_t[i] = np.std(sig[:i + 1])
        x_t = y - t * mean_t[i]
        r_t[i] = np.ptp(x_t[:i + 1])

    r_s = r_t / s_t
    r_s = np.log(r_s)[1:]
    n = np.log(t)[1:]
    a = np.column_stack((n, np.ones(n.size)))
    [hurst_exponent, c] = np.linalg.lstsq(a, r_s)[0]
    return hurst_exponent
```

Comment: Does the signal have any special properties or would it be appropriate to test with random values of a given length?

Comment: @AlexV you could test with random values of a given length.  Currently, the length is anywhere between 7680 and 153600.

Answer (score 5):

A few observations:

---

`s_t = np.zeros(n)` and `r_t = np.zeros(n)` are more than you need. Since you don't actually use the array values but solely overwrite them, you can use [`np.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) here.

---

You're doing quite a bit of redundant work in the `for` loop.

When calculating `s_t[i]`, numpy basically has to repeat all the computations it has already done for `s_t[i-1]`. If you have a look at the definition of [`np.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), you can see that the mean plays a role here. Since you have already come up with a nice solution for the mean value, you could reuse it here:

```py
s_t = np.empty(n)

for i in range(n):
    s_t[i] = np.mean((sig[:i+1] - mean_t[i])**2)
    ...
s_t = np.sqrt(s_t)
```

I validated this against the original code with `np.allclose`.

`r_t` also has some extra work that you can get rid of. At the moment your code does the following:

```py
x_t = y - t * mean_t[i]
r_t[i] = np.ptp(x_t[:i + 1])
```

All the values of `x_t` at `[i+1:n]` are computed, but never used, so you can do

```py
r_t[i] = np.ptp(y[:i+1] - t[:i+1] * mean_t[i])
```

instead, without changing the outcome. You could also write this as two list comprehensions:

```py
s_t = np.sqrt(
    np.array([np.mean((sig[:i+1] - mean_t[i])**2) for i in range(n)])
)
r_t = np.array([np.ptp(y[:i+1] - t[:i+1] * mean_t[i]) for i in range(n)])
```

Or even a single one if you'd like to get a little bit creative:

```
rs_t = np.array([
    [
        np.mean((sig[:i + 1] - mean_t[i])**2),
        np.ptp(y[:i + 1] - t[:i + 1] * mean_t[i])
    ] for i in range(n)
])
rs_t[:, 0] = np.sqrt(rs_t[:, 0])
```

A fully vectorized computation of `x_t` I have come up with, starting from

```
x_t = y.reshape(1, -1) - mean_t.reshape(-1, 1) @ t.reshape(1, -1)
```

is considerably slower than the looped version.

---

I'm actually not quite sure about the rest of the code from this point on at the moment. I will have to take a closer look to give a meaningful review performancewise. As a first non-functional feedback I would like to invite you to think about more meaningful variable names in the future. Especially there at the end of the code around the least-squares optimization, they are quite hard to understand.

---

I did some timing of different versions of this algorithm. The full benchmark code can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alexvorndran/aad69fa741e579aad093608ccaab4fe1). This is what I got so far (for `n=15360`):

```
base:              3.748915s
better_loop:       2.605374s
double_lc:         2.430255s
single_lc:         2.445943s
-----------------------
base_numba:        0.866583s
better_loop_numba: 0.813630s
double_lc_numba:   0.776361s
single_lc_numba*:  N/A
```

The lower group of results uses [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), a just-in-time compiler for Python code, that can sometimes help to speed up loops. Unfortunately, numba does not support all types of array operations in its fast `nonpython` mode, e.g. I could not get the single list comprehension version to properly work with numba.

The results are actually a little bit worse than I had originally expected, especially without numba, but there is still a good amount profiling work to be done here.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice.  By the way, the variable names match the symbols of the numbers used in the hurst exponent calculation E[R(n)/S(n)]=Cn^h

Comment: If you refer to a mathematical formula, I find it quite helpful to link to the resource you are getting it from, or at least a short "natural language" description in a comment (where necessary). Sometimes authors use notation that slightly differs from "the usual way", though I have to admit I've never heard of the Hurst exponent before this question, so I'm maybe not the best person to judge this.